# Select max time from second table JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT q.uid, q.title, q.category_id, CONCAT(CONCAT(q.text,'\n'),a.answer) as description
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT question_id, crdate, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '|| ') answer
     FROM answers
     GROUP BY question_id
     ORDER BY crdate DESC
) a ON q.uid = a.question_id
WHERE q.deleted = 0 AND q.answers > 0
```

I want to select uid, title and category id from first table, all text and **MAX** crdate of answers from second table. This query select Min crdate. How I should change it?

**UPD**
I have tables questions and answers. As the names of tables I select questions and answers. One question may has several answers. I want concat all answers in one variable (later concat some variables in one for full-text search) and select crdate of last answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT q.uid, q.title, q.category_id, CONCAT(CONCAT(q.text,'\n'),a.answer) as description
FROM questions q
LEFT JOIN (
     SELECT question_id, max(crdate) as crdate, GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '|| ') answer
     FROM answers
     GROUP BY question_id
     ORDER BY crdate DESC
) a ON q.uid = a.question_id
WHERE q.deleted = 0 AND q.answers > 0 
GROUP BY q.uid
```

Comment: it's strangely, but yes

Comment: It will give max value from answers table only

Answer (score 1):

Use two joins:

```
SELECT q.uid, q.title, q.category_id, CONCAT(CONCAT(q.text,'\n'),a.answer) as description
FROM questions q LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT a.question_id, a.crdate, GROUP_CONCAT(a.text SEPARATOR '|| ') answer
      FROM answers a JOIN
           (SELECT a2.question_id, MAX(a2.crdate) as maxcr
            FROM answers a2
            GROUP BY a2.question_id
           ) a2
           ON a2.question_id = a.question_id and a2.maxcr = a.crdate
      GROUP BY question_id
     ) a
     ON q.uid = a.question_id
WHERE q.deleted = 0 AND q.answers > 0 
GROUP BY q.uid;
```

The innermost subquery gets the maximum create date for the answers for questions.  The middle subquery does what you want, concatenating the answers together.

It is unclear what the outer `GROUP BY` is doing.  Is it really necessary?  Why are you using `GROUP BY` with no aggregation functions?  What values should be used for the other other columns in the outer `SELECT`?  Your question doesn't provide enough information to address these issues, but the query still looks suspect even after getting the most recent `crdate` for answers.

Comment: You are right, group by isn't necessary. I've update my question.